# converting yyyy-mm in string format to a month name var javascript

Tags: javascript

if I had a string like this:

```
var dte = '2017-07'
```

how would I convert that to another var with a value of 'July'?

Comment: Err... `'2017-07'` is not a Date object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var dte = '2017-07'
var months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var another = months[+dte.split('-')[1] - 1]
console.log(another);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `split()` function like this:

```
    var dte = "2017-07";
    var res = dte.split("-");
```

Res is an array of each part of the split, so access the month number by typing `res[1]`. Then I would compare the number in a `switch`-statement and get out the month name.

Answer (score 0):

First you split the string in "yyyy", "-" and "mm". Then you compare the last string,  "mm" with paterns that correspond to the correct month. You could do this with 2 string arrays. 1 has the paterns, "01", "02" etc. The other has names, "januari", "februari" etc. Iiterate the for loop over the first array. When you have a match, you know the word you are looking for is in the other array, at the same index.